# Firebase function onWrite not being called

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement a trigger using Firebase Functions, that duplicates some data in the database. I want to watch all additions at `votes/user/vote`, the structure is:

[image]

And the code I tried is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.duplicateFeedback = functions.database.ref('/votes/{userId}/voteId')
    .onWrite(event => {
        const userId = event.params.userId;
        const voteId = event.data.key();
        const vote = event.data.val();
        console.log(`New feedback from user ${userId}: { description: "${vote.feedback}", score: ${vote.rating}}`);

        return;
    });
```

But I can't even get it triggered.. Any clues what's wrong with my function? I bet is related with the reference, but I can't figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, the function is triggered by a write to

```
exports.duplicateFeedback = functions.database.ref('/votes/{userId}/voteId')
```

which would be triggered by something like this:

```
votes: {
    00000_josemi_foo: {
        voteId: {
            // data
        }
    }
}
```

But you're not looking for the child `voteId`, you're looking for any child of `{userId}`, such as `-33`, so you need to use a wildcard:

```
exports.duplicateFeedback = functions.database.ref('/votes/{userId}/{voteId}')
```