# Firebase function .onWrite not working?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Ok, I have looked at similar questions like [Firebase function onWrite not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773794/firebase-function-onwrite-not-being-called) and thought it was my fault getting the reference, but I have no idea what is happening here with my Firebase functions.

I am just trying to get a function to write to my database when a write has been made to database. I followed the firebase tutorial exactly:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// const gl = require('getlocation');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.enterLocation = functions.database.ref('/Users/{name}') //brackets is client param
    .onWrite(event => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      // const original = event.data.val();
      console.log('SKYLAR HERE:', event.params.name);
      // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as

      return firebase.database().ref('/Users/{name}').set({ location: 'test loc' });
  });
```

The function is being run, yet in my logs I get a pretty unhelpful error that it is getting the {name} param, and data is definitely written to my database, however my SERVER code is not writing:

[image]

I get -

> ReferenceError: firebase is not defined at
>   exports.enterLocation.functions.database.ref

Which makes no sense as it is defined. I just want to add an extra child under the user I create, like I do already with "password"

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here.  First, you haven't defined `firebase` anywhere in your code.  I think you meant to use `admin` instead to use the Admin SDK.

Second, it looks like you're trying to do variable interpolation into a string to build the name of the ref.  Your syntax is wrong here.

I imagine you're trying to say this instead in your last line of code:

```
return admin.database().ref(`/Users/${name}`).set({ location: 'test loc' });
```

Note the backticks on the string quotes.  That JavaScript syntax lets you use `${exp}` to insert the contents of some expression in the string.

It turns out you don't even need to use the admin SDK here.  Since you're trying to write back to the same location that triggered the function, you can just use the ref that comes from the event object:

```
return event.data.adminRef.set({ location: 'test loc' });
```

Comment: Do you know why it is deleting the existing child I had created, password?

Comment: `set()` replaces everything at a location.  `update()` adds the given values to the existing data.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#update

Answer (score 1):

instead of this:

```
 return firebase.database().ref('/Users/{name}').set({ location: 'test loc' });
```

use this:

```
 return admin.database().ref('/Users/{name}').set({ location: 'test loc' });
```